# Overriding OpenVPN's DNS Settings to Dorm Network DNS Settings

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

I use OpenVPN smoothly with Windows 10 behind my dorm network's http proxy. When I use **Linux Mint** with same client.ovpn, I can Auth successfully.But when I inspect traffic with wireshark, I see that DNS packages go to dorm network DNS server. I Can't Override OpenVPN's DNS Settings to Dorm Network DNS Server. I tried to use **scripts**, **editing resolve.conf**, **disabling resolve-service** but couldn't work it out.

**So, How can I override it ? I want my Linux to use OpenVPN DNS system wide settings just like Windows 10.**

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out !! DNS works different between linux and windows.In windows, when our vpn server push dns settings to the tun0 interface(which openvpn creates) it works !

you can set different DNS server ip for different adaptor in windows. But in linux, you can use only single DNS server for every adaptor.

You use whatever writed in etc/resolve.conf in linux as a DNS server(example nameservers DORM_DNS_SERVER_IP).

So you need to override NetworkManager.It could be possible by means of 3 method. There is no alternative to achive it:

**1**- Install openresolv(download it for your linux.).

**2**- edit /etc/resolveconf.conf(add nameservers DNS_IP_YOU_WANT)

**3**-edit client.ovpn (add this 2 line up up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf)

3.directive makes new resolve.conf using openresolve app and resolveconf.conf file automatically. OpenVPN linux client capable of using openresolve with openvpn build-in */etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf script

If /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf doesnt exists, find in internet and paste them in that directory.

**So it works !!!**

I am shocked because nobody told it anywhere before in internet.